# Trying to figure out $.post callback functionality for jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, .post

I have a jquery script that is working fine except being able to send the data via $.post and receive a response back.  here is the relevant code:

```
$.post(
    'test.php',
    { userfname: f.editfname, userlname: f.editlname, userid: v.user }, 
    callback: function(data) {
        $.prompt('You have successfully added this book to your cart!');
    }
);
```

I want the results of test.php to be placed inside the results div

Comment: what is $.prompt? can you give us some markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code contains invalid syntax. Try this:

```
$.post('test.php',
{
    userfname: f.editfname,
    userlname:f.editlname,
    userid:v.user
}, 
function(data)
{
    $.prompt('You have successfully added this book to your cart!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this you mean?

```
$("div#results").html(data);
```

Comment: $.post('test.php',{name:lname}, callback:function(data){
         $.prompt('You have successfully added '+ lname +' to your list!'); 
         $("div#results").html(data);
       });